# Replacing TimeSK for Date in a time dimension. Can I use both?

Tags: date, ssas

I am modifying a Time dimension.
In addition to integer TimeId, I added Day as date column and made it a key.

My measure groups are still linked to time dimension by Timeid.
I am changing dimension usage one by one.
I took the first dimenssion group and added Day column.
However **I can't re-link Facts and dimTime on a new Day column**.
When I change Granularity Attribute from TimeId, to Day, I only have a choice of

- Year
- QuarterKey
- MonthKey

dimension columns.

1. Is it possible to link some fact tables by TimeIdSK (usage is key) and other by Day column (usage is regular)? Could I use both columns when linking?
   When I browse time dimension, I only see measures that are linked through Day column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dimension designer, go the properties for the Day attribute. Make sure that its Usage property is set to Key (and change the TimeId's Usage property to Regular). Also for the Day attribute, make sure that the KeyColumn property is set to Day.